# '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: bash, cygwin

I found one error, while executing a python script in cygwin.

**Error is :-**

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

**Commmand is**

```
/cygdrive/c/python27/python MYSCRIPT.py -p ../../MYFOLDERNAME/file
```

I didn't get any answer related to this command on SO/google.

Comment: And what does `MYSCRIPT.py` do? Is the error printed by Python or by cygwin?

Comment: @MartijinPieters Its by CYGWIN.

Comment: Then I'll remove the `python` tag.

Comment: Is there any whitespace in `MYSCRIPT` or `MYFOLDERNAME`? Have you tried quoting the paths? Also, how are you sure that the error is by cygwin and not python?

Comment: the shell cannot produce that message. I have no idea what you're doing. *try to copy-paste the command you've posted*

Comment: MYSCRIPT.py takes custom CLI argument for -p <filename> which is simply a text file that is read by the python script. The error is not being thrown by the script i have written. It is possible that maybe some module in python libraries is doing it.